# How to write with PHP a 2D JSON

Tags: php, json

How can I write something like this:

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
      "statement" : "CREATE (n) RETURN id(n)"
    } ]
 }
```

in a JSON format using PHP?
I try this:

```
  $dataArr = array("statement" => "CREATE (n) RETURN id(n)");
```

But how to add the "statements" correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$array = array('statements' => array("statement" => "CREATE (n) RETURN id(n)"));
json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**EDIT:**

Actually if you want preserve to have `"statements":[{...}]`,
it should be:

```
$array = array('statements' => array(array("statement" => "CREATE (n) RETURN  id(n)")));
```